# how to find a pattern in java strings

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, methods

i am very new to coding so sorry if my questions are dumb. I was asked by my teacher to write a java program that will show all the possible combinations of the chars 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' into strings but with these rules:

1. the strings have to be 4 characters long.
2. letters can repeat in the same string.
3. the characters 'a' and 'd' can't be in the same string.
4. the character 'b' ALWAYS has to be followed by 'a'.

i started to write a program but i'm stumped.
i have tried using ArrayLists but i couldn't get it to work.

Comment: What's stopping you from inspecting `str` to see if it meets your rules? You can use [String.indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_indexof.asp) to enforce rules #3 and #4.  Just don't output the string if it doesn't meet all criteria...

Comment: honestly i didn't know how to use it or what it is. I have exhausted the notions that the teacher gave and have been on this all day trying different loops and stuff. i will read up on that thanks.

Comment: Parenthesis placement is really important in these scenarios. I'll update my answer to include how it evaluates.

Comment: Please share your code attempt as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, in terms of calculating permutations.

You'll just need to check the values, before adding the *String*.

Here is an example.

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
String s;
char w, x, y, z;
for (w = 'a'; w <= 'd'; w++)
    for (x = 'a'; x <= 'd'; x++)
        for (y = 'a'; y <= 'd'; y++)
            for (z = 'a'; z <= 'd'; z++) {
                s = "%s%s%s%s".formatted(w, x, y, z);
                if (s.indexOf('a') != -1 && s.indexOf('d') != -1) continue;
                if (w == 'b' && x != 'a') continue;
                if (x == 'b' && y != 'a') continue;
                if (y == 'b' && z != 'a') continue;
                if (z == 'b') continue;
                list.add(s);
            }
```

Output

```
aaaa aaac aaba aaca aacc abaa abac acaa acac acba 
acca accc baaa baac baba baca bacc caaa caac caba 
caca cacc cbaa cbac ccaa ccac ccba ccca cccc cccd 
ccdc ccdd cdcc cdcd cddc cddd dccc dccd dcdc dcdd 
ddcc ddcd dddc dddd
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, as others have stated you just need to validate the output string to ensure it meets your criteria.

```
public class Main {
    static StringBuilder valid = new StringBuilder();
    static StringBuilder invalid = new StringBuilder();

    // START Tracking / formatting vars.
    static int permsPerRow = 10;
    static int invalidNumsAdded = 0;
    static int validPerms = 0;
    static int invalidPerms = 0;
    // END Tracking / formatting vars.

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        calculatePerms();
    }

    private static void calculatePerms() {
        char[] chars = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
        int numsAdded = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < chars.length; j++) {
                for(int k = 0; k < chars.length; k++) {
                    for(int z = 0; z < chars.length; z++) {
                        // Unsure why, but having the last char in the array be the first mutation bothered me, so
                        // I reversed that.
                        String str = chars[z]+""+chars[k]+""+chars[j]+""+chars[i];
                        // We have the string now, we just need to validate it against the provided rules.
                        if(validString(str)) {
                            // I added the chunk below for formatting, this can be ignored.
                            if(numsAdded >= permsPerRow) {
                                valid.append("\n");
                                numsAdded = 0;
                            }
                            // It's been validated, I append it to the valid StringBuilder.
                            valid.append(str+" ");
                            validPerms++;
                            numsAdded++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Valid Perms: "+validPerms);
        System.out.println(valid.toString()+"\n");
        System.out.println("Invalid Perms: "+invalidPerms);
        System.out.println(invalid.toString());
    }

    private static boolean validString(String str) {
        // a and d can't be in the same string
        // b always has to be followed by a
        if(str.toLowerCase().contains("a") && str.toLowerCase().contains("d")) {
            logInvalid(str);
            return false;
        }
        char[] strChars = str.toCharArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < strChars.length; i++) {
            if(strChars[i] == 'b') {
                // Check to make sure b isn't the last char in the sequence. If it is, then 'a' can't follow it,
                // and it's an invalid permutation.
                if(i+1 > strChars.length-1) {
                    logInvalid(str);
                    return false;
                }
                // If the char following b isn't a then it's not a valid perm.
                if(strChars[i+1] != 'a') {
                    logInvalid(str);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    // I added an invalid string builder as well, to track the number of invalid combinations, mostly to spot check
    // and ensure the 'invalid' permutations were actually breaking the rules.
    private static void logInvalid(String str) {
        if(invalidNumsAdded >= permsPerRow) {
            invalid.append("\n");
            invalidNumsAdded = 0;
        }
        invalid.append(str+" ");
        invalidPerms++;
        invalidNumsAdded++;
    }
}
```

Which results in:

```
Valid Perms: 44
aaaa baaa caaa abaa cbaa acaa ccaa aaba baba caba 
acba ccba aaca baca caca acca ccca aaac baac caac 
abac cbac acac ccac aacc bacc cacc accc cccc dccc 
cdcc ddcc ccdc dcdc cddc dddc cccd dccd cdcd ddcd 
ccdd dcdd cddd dddd 

Invalid Perms: 212
daaa bbaa dbaa bcaa dcaa adaa bdaa cdaa ddaa daba 
abba bbba cbba dbba bcba dcba adba bdba cdba ddba 
daca abca bbca cbca dbca bcca dcca adca bdca cdca 
ddca aada bada cada dada abda bbda cbda dbda acda 
bcda ccda dcda adda bdda cdda ddda aaab baab caab 
daab abab bbab cbab dbab acab bcab ccab dcab adab 
bdab cdab ddab aabb babb cabb dabb abbb bbbb cbbb 
dbbb acbb bcbb ccbb dcbb adbb bdbb cdbb ddbb aacb 
bacb cacb dacb abcb bbcb cbcb dbcb accb bccb cccb 
dccb adcb bdcb cdcb ddcb aadb badb cadb dadb abdb 
bbdb cbdb dbdb acdb bcdb ccdb dcdb addb bddb cddb 
dddb daac bbac dbac bcac dcac adac bdac cdac ddac 
aabc babc cabc dabc abbc bbbc cbbc dbbc acbc bcbc 
ccbc dcbc adbc bdbc cdbc ddbc dacc abcc bbcc cbcc 
dbcc bccc adcc bdcc aadc badc cadc dadc abdc bbdc 
cbdc dbdc acdc bcdc addc bddc aaad baad caad daad 
abad bbad cbad dbad acad bcad ccad dcad adad bdad 
cdad ddad aabd babd cabd dabd abbd bbbd cbbd dbbd 
acbd bcbd ccbd dcbd adbd bdbd cdbd ddbd aacd bacd 
cacd dacd abcd bbcd cbcd dbcd accd bccd adcd bdcd 
aadd badd cadd dadd abdd bbdd cbdd dbdd acdd bcdd 
addd bddd
```

Update for the evaluation issue in the most recent edit:

```
// Since 2 and 3 evaluate to true (b is present, and the last index of b + 1 is not a (it's c), this check passes.
//           (1)                ||          (2                  &&                 3)
if( (str.lastIndexOf('b') == 3) || (str.lastIndexOf("b") != -1) && (str.charAt(str.lastIndexOf('b') + 1) != 'a')) {
// remove these parenthesis   ^    ^  and it works.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StringCombinations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> combinations = generateCombinations();
        
        for (String combination : combinations) {
            System.out.println(combination);
        }
    }

    private static List<String> generateCombinations() {
        List<String> combinations = new ArrayList<>();

      
        for (char firstChar : "abcd".toCharArray()) {
            for (char secondChar : "abcd".toCharArray()) {
                for (char thirdChar : "abcd".toCharArray()) {
                    for (char fourthChar : "abcd".toCharArray()) {
                      
                        if (firstChar != 'd' && fourthChar != 'a' && (secondChar != 'b' || thirdChar == 'a')) {

                            String combination = "" + firstChar + secondChar + thirdChar + fourthChar;
                            combinations.add(combination);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return combinations;
    }
}
```

> Please find the working sample [here](https://onlinegdb.com/erOVQ0jm-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a way using recursion, calls itself until given condition is met.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] chars = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    generateCombinations(chars, "");
}

private static void generateCombinations(char[] chars, String current) {
    if (current.length() == 4) {
        // Check if 'a' and 'd' are not in the same string
        if (!(current.contains("a") && current.contains("d"))) {
            System.out.println(current);
        }
    } else {
        for (char ch : chars) {
            // 'b' always has to be followed by 'a'
            if (ch == 'b' && !current.contains("a")) {
                continue;
            }

            // Check if adding the current character violates the rules
            if (!(ch == 'a' && current.contains("b")) && !(ch == 'd' && current.contains("b"))) {
                generateCombinations(chars, current + ch);
            }
        }
    }
```